# JAR file automatically terminates on remote Ubuntu server after a day

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ubuntu, jar

I have a jar file, which was built using maven (the app is spring-boot). I deployed it on a remote server using `nohup java -jar app.jar` command. It works for a day or so and then stops working. The logs in `nohup` file are not informative and I could not figure out what's the reason for that. By `stops working`, I mean - the application just terminates, it is not working.

Here is the output of the `nohup` file:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2022-02-21 06:19:32.288  INFO 74013 --- [           main] kz.iuth.platonus.demo.DemoApplication    : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_131 on user-ProLiant-ML30-Gen9 with PID 74013 (/home/user/iuth_app/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by user in /home/user/iuth_app)
2022-02-21 06:19:32.290  INFO 74013 --- [           main] kz.iuth.platonus.demo.DemoApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-02-21 06:19:32.913  INFO 74013 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-02-21 06:19:32.981  INFO 74013 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 60 ms. Found 11 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-02-21 06:19:33.485  INFO 74013 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2022-02-21 06:19:33.497  INFO 74013 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-02-21 06:19:33.497  INFO 74013 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2022-02-21 06:19:33.545  INFO 74013 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-02-21 06:19:33.545  INFO 74013 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1209 ms
2022-02-21 06:19:33.691  INFO 74013 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-02-21 06:19:34.035  INFO 74013 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-02-21 06:19:34.074  INFO 74013 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-02-21 06:19:34.115  INFO 74013 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.1.Final
2022-02-21 06:19:34.249  INFO 74013 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-02-21 06:19:34.348  INFO 74013 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2022-02-21 06:19:34.819  INFO 74013 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-02-21 06:19:34.826  INFO 74013 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-21 06:19:35.564  WARN 74013 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-02-21 06:19:36.010  INFO 74013 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
2022-02-21 06:19:36.018  INFO 74013 --- [           main] kz.iuth.platonus.demo.DemoApplication    : Started DemoApplication in 4.109 seconds (JVM running for 4.502)
2022-02-21 06:19:53.481  INFO 74013 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-02-21 06:19:53.481  INFO 74013 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-02-21 06:19:53.493  INFO 74013 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-02-21 06:19:58.354  WARN 74013 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]


.....


    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]

2022-02-21 23:08:17.439  WARN 74013 --- [nio-9090-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
2022-02-21 23:30:31.755  INFO 74013 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-02-21 23:30:31.762  INFO 74013 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-02-21 23:30:31.769  INFO 74013 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I'm not sure what's the problem. Please, feel free to ask more information, If you need and I will edit.

Comment: A common cause of behavior like this is Linux's out of memory killer. Perhaps the host is over-committed in terms of memory and/or there's a memory leak in your application that causes the heap to grow to a point where the host's memory has been exhausted. The OS's log files will help to identify the former and a profiler or heap dumps the latter.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I'm quite new to Linux, but I get your point. I tried `dmesg | less
` to see If there is any killed process as stated in this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/709336/how-to-find-out-why-process-was-killed-on-server. However, simple "kill" substring search did not show any matches in the terminal output.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson The last entry in `kern.log` file was on Feb 18th, whereas I ran the `jar` file yesterday and it stopped today. I got the output of the `kern.log` file with this command: `sudo cat /var/log/kern.log*`

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I checked `/var/log/syslog` and there is no "kill" substring there, as well.